# Pointers in C++ / Linked List

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

Lets say in my linked list class I am keeping a pointer that refers to the head of the linked list...

In one of the member functions when I write this code...

```
Node *cur = head;
cur = cur->next;
```

why doesn't head change `head->next`?

if I write `cur = NULL`; will it make head `null`?

Comment: Well, what *is* a variable? (Ignore reference parameters and all that jazz)

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what results you get?

Comment: It works the same as `int x = 0; int y = x; y = 1;`. Why doesn't the value of `x` change when we assign to `y`?

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming that `head` is a `Node *`. In this case, when you say `cur = cur->next` you are changing where `cur` points, but `head` will remain pointing to the head of the list because you haven't changed where it points.

```
Cur----------|
             |
             V       next
Head -----> Item 1--------->Item 2
```

`cur = cur->next` yields the following:

```
Cur--------------------------|
                             |
                     next    V      
Head -----> Item 1--------->Item 2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you write:

```
Node *cur = head;
cur = NULL;
```

then `cur` will be pointing to nothing and nothing will happen to `head`.

If you write:

```
Node *cur = head;
cur = cur->next;
cur = NULL;
```

The same thing will happen (`cur` will be pointing to nothing and nothing will happen to `head`) unless `head` was `NULL`, in which case, you'll crash on `cur = cur->next;`

If you're trying to set `head->next` to `NULL` via the `cur` pointer, you can do so with the following:

```
Node *cur = head;
cur->next = NULL;
```

I can see your confusion is coming from the nature of pointers.  When you say `Node *cur = head;` you are creating a `Node` pointer that points to the same memory address as `head`.  If you set `cur` to something else via `cur = NULL`, then you're only changing **what `cur` points to**, not **the value of what it's pointing to** and therefore, `head` is left alone.

When you use `cur->next = NULL` instead, you're modifying the `next` member of **what `cur` points to**.  This is also the `next` member of what `head` points to and therefore, the change is also reflected in `head->next`.

Comment: cur.next = NULL;  will this change head?

Comment: @MadanLal `head` and `cur` point to the same thing, any operations on either one will affect the other.

Comment: @MadanLal Kind of... you need to use `->` because `cur` is a pointer so it would be `cur->next = NULL`.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: No, that's not true.  Any operations on the thing that `cur` points to will affect the thing `head` points to (until they point to different things).  But operations on `cur`, such as `cur = x;`, will have no effect on `head`.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen You should probably clarify that to if you perform any operations on the *contents* of `head` or `cur`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley So you're saying `cur->next = NULL` won't affect `head` at all ? Or are just clarifying that the operations on both `cur` and `head` only modify the other while they still point to the same thing?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Right, `cur->next = NULL` doesn't affect head.  It doesn't even affect cur.  It affects the thing that cur points to.  I may be nitpicking, but I just didn't want Madan to get the wrong idea when you said *"head and cur point to the same thing, any operations on either one will affect the other."*, because that is definitely not true.  As is obvious if you say `cur = x;`, a statement that definitely has an effect on cur, yet has no effect whatsoever on head.

Answer (score 1):

cur is pointer, cur = cur->next; merely make cur point somewhere else, why should it change head?